# Azure DataFactory use Variable in Azure Function body activity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

#### Update:

With the array of strings my function returns : `Result: Failure Exception: ValueError: HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data Stack`

---

I want to trigger an Az Function with Data Factory by passing a variable within the body of the function.
This is the way I defined the body:

```
{
"container": "video-assets",
"latest_files": "@variables('latestFiles')"
}
```

However it seems not working as the logs in my function show `{'container': 'video-assets', 'latest_files': "@variables('latestFiles')"}`
The "latestFiles" variable is an array of strings.
This is my little pipeline:
[image]
How can I pass a variable in the body of an azure function?

Comment: You can try adding curly braces to denote the function: "@{variables('latestFiles')}

Comment: With the array of strings my function returns : `Result: Failure Exception: ValueError: HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data Stack`

Comment: Not sure this is the final solution, but if you are trying to pass it as an array, then remove the "s around the function call.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try this `@json(concat('{"container": "video-assets","latest_files":',variables('latestFiles'),'}'))`. It will convert json string to json object.
[image]